# How to edit Nested Table in Datatables Editor

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have some tables:

```
    `table_customer` (
      `id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `note` text NOT NULL
    )
    
    `table_address` (
      `id_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `zipcode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
      `phone` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
    )
    
    `table_customer_address` (
      `id_customer_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `is_default_address` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      `is_current_address` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
    )
    
    `table_service` (
      `id_service` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `service_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    )
    
    `table_customer_service` (
      `id_customer_service` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_service` int(11) NOT NULL
    )
    
    `table_user` (
      `id_user` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `usergroup` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
    )
    
    `table_user_customer` (
      `id_user_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_customer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `date_add` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

- 1 User can manage multi Customers
- 1 Customer have multi Address
- 1 Customer have multi Service

Now, I want to show all information of the customers (default address on homepage and all addresses, service in Editor) have a Manager. I have no problem with Select. I show fine as I want (as the picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIxvO.png)

But in the editor (eg: Edit Customer 1), it doesn't work:

- It show corrected selected service. But when I choose another service and click update, it delete all services of this customer
- It don't show any address of customers

This is my server script:

```
    $editor = Editor::inst( $db, 'table_user_customer', 'id_user_customer' )
        ->fields(
            Field::inst( 'table_user_customer.id_customer' )->set(false),
            Field::inst( 'table_user_customer.id_user' )
                ->options( Options::inst()
                    ->table( 'table_user' )
                    ->value( 'id_user' )
                    ->label( 'username' )
                ),      
            Field::inst( 'table_user.username' ),   
            Field::inst( 'table_customer.fullname' ),
            Field::inst( 'table_customer.birthday' ),
            Field::inst( 'table_customer.email' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.id_address' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.address' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.city' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.state' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.zipcode' ),
            Field::inst( 'default_address.phone' ),
            Field::inst( 'table_customer.note' ),
        )
        ->leftJoin( 'table_user', 'table_user.id_user', '=', 'table_user_customer.id_user' )
        ->leftJoin( 'table_customer', 'table_customer.id_customer', '=', 'table_user_customer.id_customer' )
        ->leftJoin(
            'table_customer_address',
            'table_customer_address.id_customer = table_customer.id_customer AND table_customer_address.is_default_address = 1'
        )
        ->leftJoin(
            'table_address as default_address',
            'default_address.id_address = table_customer_address.id_address'
        )
        ->join(
            Mjoin::inst( 'table_service' )
                ->link( 'table_user_customer.id_customer', 'table_customer_service.id_customer' )
                ->link( 'table_service.id_service', 'table_customer_service.id_service' )       
                ->fields(
                    Field::inst( 'id_service' )
                        ->validator( Validate::required() )
                        ->options( Options::inst()
                            ->table( 'table_service' )
                            ->value( 'id_service' )
                            ->label( 'service_name' )
                        ),
                    Field::inst( 'service_name' )
                )
        )
        ->join(
            Mjoin::inst( 'table_address' )
                ->link( 'table_user_customer.id_customer', 'table_customer_address.id_customer' )               
                ->link( 'table_address.id_address', 'table_customer_address.id_address' )   
                ->fields(
                    Field::inst( 'id_address' ),
                    Field::inst( 'address' ),
                    Field::inst( 'city' ),
                    Field::inst( 'state' ),
                    Field::inst( 'zipcode' ),
                    Field::inst( 'phone' ),
                )
        )   
        ->debug(true)
        ->process( $_POST )
        ->json();
```

And my js script is:

```
    <script>
    var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the table_customers
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        var addressEditor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: '../faq/controllers/fetch-history.php',
            fields: [ 
                
                {
                    "label": "Address 1",
                    "name": "table_address.address"
                },      
                {
                    "label": "City",
                    "name": "table_address.city"
                },  
                {
                    "label": "State",
                    "name": "table_address.state"
                },  
                {
                    "label": "Zipcode",
                    "name": "table_address.zipcode"
                },  
                {
                    "label": "Phone",
                    "name": "table_address.phone"
                },  
            ]
        } );
    
        var serviceEditor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: '../faq/controllers/fetch-history.php',
            fields: [           
                {
                    "label": "Service Name",
                    "name": "table_service[].service_name"
                }   
            ]
        } );
        
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "../faq/controllers/fetch-history.php",
            table: "#table_customer",
            fields: [ 
                {
                    "name": "table_user_customer.id_customer",
                    type: "hidden"
                },      
                {
                    "name": "table_service.id_service",
                    type: "hidden"
                },              
                {
                    "label": "Full Name",
                    "name": "table_customer.fullname"
                },
                {
                    "label": "DOB",
                    "name": "table_customer.birthday"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Note",
                    "name": "table_customer.note"
                },          
                {
                    "label": "User",
                    "name": "table_user_customer.id_user",
                    type: "select"
                },          
                {
                    label: 'Service',
                    name: 'table_service[].id_service',
                    type: 'datatable',
                    multiple: true          
                },          
                {
                    label: 'Addresses',
                    name: 'table_address[].id_address',
                    type: 'datatable',
    
                    config: {
                        buttons: [
                            { extend: 'create', editor: addressEditor },
                            { extend: 'edit',   editor: addressEditor },
                            { extend: 'remove', editor: addressEditor }
                        ],
                    }               
                }
                
                    
            ],
            bootstrap: {
                floatingLabels: true
            }
        } );
        /*
        // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
        $('#table_customer').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
            editor.inline( this );
        } );
        */
        $('#table_customer').DataTable( {
            columnDefs: [{
                "defaultContent": "-",
                "targets": "_all"
            }],     
            //serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            //lengthChange: false,
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            ajax: {
                url: "../faq/controllers/fetch-history.php",
                type: 'POST'
            },
            order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
            columns: [
                {
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '',
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    orderable: false
                },          
                { data: "table_user_customer.id_customer" },
                
                { data: "table_customer.fullname" },
                { data: "table_customer.birthday" },
                { data: "table_customer.email" },
                { data: "default_address.address"},
                { data: "default_address.city" },
                { data: "default_address.state" },
                { data: "default_address.zipcode" },
                { data: "default_address.phone" },
                { data: "table_customer.note" },
                { data: "table_service", render: "[, ].service_name" },
                { data: "table_address", render: "[, ].id_address" },
                { data: "table_user.username", editField: "table_user_customer.id_user" },
                
            ],
            select: {
                style:    'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            buttons: [
                { extend: "create", editor: editor },
                { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
                { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
            ],
            
        } );
    } );
    </script>
```

I want it to work as the picture:

[image]